# I'm using Geodjango to implement a geolocation system for my system but it keeps raising a value error

Tags: python, django, django-models, gis, geodjango

'''from django.contrib.gis.db  import models

class Store(models.Model):

```
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    coords= models.PointField()
    store_id = models.IntegerField()'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django and Geodjango models must be imported separately.

One solution is to import django models normally and alias the spatial models import.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as sp_models

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    coords = sp_models.PointField()
    store_id = models.IntegerField()
```